# Cut down path name in Python

Tags: python, glob

This is my current code:

```
directory = "C:/Users/test/Desktop/test/sign off img"
choices = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "*.jpg"))
print(choices)
```

This will return me every single path to all .JPG files inside that specific folder.

As an example, here is the output for the current above code:

```
['C:/Users/test/Desktop/test/sign off img\\SFDG001 0102400OL - signed.jpg', 'C:/Users/test/Desktop/test/sign off img\\SFDG001 0102400OL.jpg']
```

How can I get the output to only return the ending of the path?

This is my desire outcome:

```
['SFDG001 0102400OL - signed.jpg', 'SFDG001 0102400OL.jpg']
```

Same path, but just the end string is returned.

Comment: I have added an answer to your question. Let me know if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) function:

```py
>>> import os
>>> files = os.listdir("C:/Users/test/Desktop/test/sign off img")
>>> filtered_files = [file for file in files if 'signed' in file]
```

As you can see in thee docs, `os.listdir` uses the current directory as default argument, i.e., if you don't pass a value. Otherwise, it will use the path you pass to it.

Comment: hi @Imiguelvargasf thanks for the answer! one more thing if you don't mind.. how can I return the current path and only return file that contains specific text such as `signed`? With the current code

Comment: @98Ed, once you get the files, you can use a list comprehension with a filter in order to take just the files that satisfy your condition. I just updated my answer, I hope that helps you.

Comment: I am working on a small project currently, but heavily rely on the internet.. any suggestions how I can rely on the internet less?

Comment: @98Ed, I think it is fine to rely on the Internet. Honestly, most of the times I am not sure how to solve a problem, and I find that somebody else has already solve a problem I want to solve, so it is nice to use their work and effort as starting point. I think what you want is to be more familiar with Python, so I suggest you to try solving some programming problems as the ones in [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) or you can take challenges in [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/python).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `pathlib.Path` over `os` most of the time. Try this, for example:

```py
from pathlib import Path

directory = Path("C:/Users/test/Desktop/test/sign off img")
choices = [path.name for path in directory.glob("*.jpg")]
```

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks for your answer once more. I've noticed you're very familiar with Python and tkinter etc.. would you kindly be able to have a private chat with me and possibly help me out with my small project? Thanks

Comment: also this returns `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'glob'`

Comment: I think it would be easier if you post your project questions normally on SO: that way, other users can also answer and benefit from the answers. As for the error, double-check that `type(directory)` is `Path`, as it will be after executing the `directory = ...` line above.

Comment: Okay @Nathan ! I'll post the project eventually, hope to see you there! :D